# Facebook Style YUI Tabs

Tags: facebook, coding-style, yui

Does anyone know how to style YUI Tabview component [1] so it will look like Facebook tabs [2]?

I am using YUI 2. A very crude attempt is below (I modified the example code given in Devtacular [3]). But it does not handle the spacing between the tabs, nor the outer lines around the selected tab.

1. http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/tabview/
2. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/121472/facebook_tab.jpg
3. http://devtacular.com/articles/bkonrad/how-to-style-an-application-like-facebook/

Thanks!

---

```
.yui-navset .yui-nav a {
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #d8dfea;
    color: #3b5998;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: hand;
}
.yui-navset .yui-nav a:hover {
    background-color: #3b5998;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.yui-navset .yui-nav .selected a {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #333333;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it will help to clarify what I want. I am not very experienced in CSS. Nonetheless, I started to modify the yui-sam-skin CSS to adapt my needs. I wonder if anyone has done it before, so I can save a lot of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up with the following CSS. It's an adaptation from the YUI documentation with trial and errors, might contain very stupid CSS errors but tabs looks like FB tabs.

```
/* .yui-navset defaults to .yui-navset-top */
.yui-navset .yui-nav,
.yui-navset .yui-navset-top .yui-nav { /* protect nested tabviews from other orientations */
    border-color: #d8dfea;
    border-style:solid;/* #2647a0; /* color between tab list and content */
    border-width:0 0 1px 0;
    Xposition:relative;
    zoom:1;
    padding-left: 4px;
}

.yui-navset .yui-nav li,
.yui-navset .yui-navset-top .yui-nav li {
    margin:0 0.16em 0 0; /* space between tabs */
    padding: 0px;
    zoom:1;
}

.yui-navset .yui-nav .selected,
.yui-navset .yui-navset-top .yui-nav .selected {
    margin:0 0.16em -1px 0; /* for overlap */
}

.yui-navset .yui-nav a,
.yui-navset .yui-navset-top .yui-nav a {
    background-color:#d8dfea;
    border:solid #a3a3a3;
    border-width: 0px; /*top right bottom left*/
    color:#3b5998;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding: 4px 8px;
}

.yui-navset .yui-nav a em,
.yui-navset .yui-navset-top .yui-nav a em {
    border:solid #a3a3a3;
    border-width:1px 0 0;
    cursor:hand;
    padding:0.25em .75em;
    left:0; right: 0; bottom: 0; /* protect from other orientations */
    top:-1px; /* for 1px rounded corners */
    position:relative;

}

.yui-navset .yui-nav .selected a,
.yui-navset .yui-nav .selected a:focus, /* no focus effect for selected */
.yui-navset .yui-nav .selected a:hover { /* no hover effect for selected */
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #333333;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0px 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #d8dfea;
}

.yui-navset .yui-nav a:hover,
.yui-navset .yui-nav a:focus {
    background-color: #3b5998;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.yui-navset .yui-nav .selected a {
    padding: 8px 8px; /* raise selected tab */
}

.yui-navset .yui-nav .selected a,
.yui-navset .yui-nav .selected a em {
    border-color: #d8dfea;
    /*border-color:#243356; /* selected tab border color */
}

.yui-navset .yui-content {
    background-color: #ffffff;/*#edf5ff;/*#D8DFEA;/*#edf5ff; /* content background color */
}

.yui-navset .yui-content,
.yui-navset .yui-navset-top .yui-content {
    /*border:0px solid #808080; /* content border */
    padding:0.25em 0.5em; /* content padding */
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-color: #d8dfea;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
}

.yui-navset .yui-content h2 {
    background-color: #ffffff; /*#edf5ff;*/
}
```